# Is there a way to save in swift keychain objects and nil?

Tags: ios, swift, keychain

I saw my code fails when I try to save String! or nil or AnyObject using swift keychain

```
func setSharedPrefrences()
{

    if (mainViewController != nil)
    {
        if (mainViewController.location_text != nil) {
            keychainSetSafe(mainViewController.location_text.text, key: StringConstans.keychain_lineName)
        }
    }
}

func keychainSetSafe(value: String!, key : String)
{
    if let nonNullValue = value
    {
        keychain.set(nonNullValue, forKey: key)
    }

}

func getSharedPrefrences()
{
    if (mainViewController != nil)
    {
        let gcmToken = keychain.get(StringConstans.keychain_gcmToken)
        if (gcmToken != nil) {
            mainViewController.userState.gcmToken = gcmToken
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to store these types in order to restore when app moves from bg to fg and again?

```
//
// Keychain helper for iOS/Swift.
//
// https://github.com/marketplacer/keychain-swift
//
// This file was automatically generated by combining multiple Swift source files.
//


// ----------------------------
//
// KeychainSwift.swift
//
// ----------------------------

import Security
import Foundation

/**

A collection of helper functions for saving text and data in the keychain.

*/
public class KeychainSwift
```

Comment: Why are you wanting to store in the KeyChain rather than just using NSUserDefaults?

Comment: As @Michael says, why are you using keychain for this?  Regardless, you can't store nil.  If a particular value is nil then you should delete the corresponding item from the keychain, then when you restore if the value isn't present you can assume that it was nil

Comment: @Michael is `NSUserDefaults` for swift also?

Comment: Yeah sure. Much easier to save to NSUserDefaults.